# How do you format a datetime field in a SelectList in MVC?

Tags: model-view-controller

I'm creating a new SelectList object and concatenating 2 fields, one is a string and the other is a DateTime. Basically I'm building a dropdownlist displaying the name and date of an event. When I try running the code I get the error ' LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'System.String ToShortDateString()' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.'

Any help would greatly be appreciated.

```
ViewBag.EventKey = new SelectList((from e in db.Events where e.Active == true select new { e.PKey, EventInfo = e.Name + " " + e.EventDate.ToShortDateString() }), "Pkey", "EventInfo");
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you're calling .ToShortDateString in statement that is going to be translated to DB query. Try following:

```
ViewBag.EventKey = new SelectList((from e in db.Events where e.Active == true select e).ToArray().Select(e => new { e.PKey, EventInfo = e.Name + " " + e.EventDate.ToShortDateString() }), "Pkey", "EventInfo");
```